# horizontal bar chart with color bar directly from a dataframe pandas object

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colorbar

I have the below code and I am wondering if I can produce a horizontal bar chart plot where the bars change colour horizontally (overtime in my case) according to a given colour map directly from a data frame object.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=ndays), columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()

# plot dataframe
df.plot(figsize=(10,5))

# TODO
# make a plot with four horizontal bars each for one column (A, B, C, D)
# the bars represent the time variation and thus should change colour according to the values in the ABCD columns mapped to cmap colour map
```

[image: df_plot_with_line]

I also include below a temporary solution using scatter plot for the purpose of visualisation what I aim for.

```
# this is what I would like plot to look like
# I use plt.scatter to show
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cmap = cm.gnuplot
ax.scatter(x=df.index, y=[0]*df.A.shape[0], c=df.A, cmap=cmap)
ax.scatter(x=df.index, y=[1]*df.A.shape[0], c=df.B, cmap=cmap)
ax.scatter(x=df.index, y=[2]*df.A.shape[0], c=df.C, cmap=cmap)
cax = ax.scatter(x=df.index, y=[3]*df.A.shape[0], c=df.D, cmap=cmap)

# vertical color bar
clim = cax.get_clim()
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[min(clim),np.mean(clim),max(clim)], orientation='vertical')
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(['Low', 'Medium', 'High'])
```

[image: my_current_solution]

Note: The question is not about scatter plot but if and how to make the result obtain with my current solution directly from the data frame object.

Comment: Is this about a scatter plot or a bar chart? In the text you write about bar chart, but the code shows a scatter. Is the question (A)How can I produce a horizontal bar chart plot where the bars change colour horizontally? Or (B) How can I produce a colorbar to map all scatter plots? Please decide and [edit] your question.

Comment: Also, an example image of what you want to achieve would help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: The question is about bar chart. My current temporary solution is using scatter plot. It is my understanding that it would be good to include what we have done already. The part with scatter plot was to help others to see what I want to achieve. In the meantime, I also figure out how to insert pictures.

Comment: Ok, so what is wrong with the current solution using a scatter plot? Please name everything that you do not want or want to have changed compared to your current solution.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Just make the same thing directly from the data frame object. The question states clearly what I want to do. What is so confusing? (Apologies for my English)

Comment: Maybe I just don't know what "directly from the data frame object" means. You do use the data frame object directly in your current solution.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, all data are in the data frame object. In the example I gave only four columns. They can be plotted easily using _line_ the default value for data frame plot function. However, I would prefer to produce a different kind of plot: _horizontal bar_ where the bar represents the variation of a specific column in the data frame over time. Therefore, the colour should change according to the values in that respective column.

Comment: Well, it seems you are looking for `df.plot(kind="mycustomwishlistplot", x="x", y="y")`, which of course does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can kind of do this through pandas, but it is really ugly.  You need to make new columns just for scatter plotting, and then pass the color argument a list of colors based on the actual data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000), 
                  columns=list('ABCD')).cumsum()

# create color normalizer
cnormer = colors.Normalize(df.min().min(), df.max().max())

# add new columns for the scatter plot
df['i'] = np.arange(1000)
for x in range(4):
    df['z{}'.format(x)] = x

# create an axis to plot on
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,3))

# make scatter plots
for x in range(4):
    df.plot(x='i', y='z{}'.format(x), kind='scatter', marker='o', edgecolor='none', 
            c=plt.cm.viridis(cnormer(df.iloc[:,x])), ax=ax)
```

You would still need to reformat the labels and ticks.

[image]

Comment: Thx for introducing how to create a color normalizer. Now, I have to figure out how to use it to change the color of each rectangle associated with the horizontal bar.